# Choosing different normal vector gives different surface integral value?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, surface-integrals

To compute surface integral of vector fields needs to find the dot product of the field and its normal vector. This is clear to me.

The question is that **why when I chose a multiple of its normal vector(i.e. normal vector was (1,-2,3) and I chose -5(1,-2,3)=(-5,10,-15) ) appears to give me another value when integrated.**

I think I make mistake I can’t address. Thank you very much for any advice <3.

Comment: The normal vector must be of unit length.

Comment: Doesn’t it get canceled already ? I remember when deriving the formula we need an unit vector and we have it by find any normal and divide them by its length then it will eventually get cancel by the dS or something like that. I’m still confused though.

Comment: No, it does not get cancelled. You first take the outward *unit* normal vector, then multiply it by the scalar differential of area to get the vector differential of area.